# Be $Im(z) \neq 0$. It follow: $Im(z^n) \neq 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Why isn't this correct?

Tags: complex-numbers

Since there is no number $n$ with $a^n = 0$ with $a \neq 0$  this should be correct, but according to my exercise quiz its not. I would be very grateful for a hint, because I haven't found a useful approach so far.

Comment: Did you mean $\forall \color{red} n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: $a^n=0\implies a=0$, but not Im$(a^n)=0\implies a^n=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $z=i$.  Then Im$(z)\ne0$ but Im$(z^2)=0$.

Comment: counterexample suffices to disprove

Comment: Oh i forgot to take the properties of $i$ into account. I should get some sleep...

Answer (score 1):

$Im(z^n) \ne (Im(z))^n$ so there is no reason that $a\ne 0\implies a^n\ne 0$ should mean that $(a + bi)^n \ne d + 0i$.  It *does* mean that $(a+bi)^n \ne 0 $ and that means that $Re((a+b)^n)$ and $Im((a+b)^n)$ can't both be equal to $0$ but that doesn't mean one can and the other doesn't.

For a quiz the must *obvious* example should but $i$ where $Im(i) = 1$ and $i^2 = -1$ and $Im(-1) = -1$.

In general $(a+bi )^n = a^n + na^{n-1}bi - {n\choose 2}a^{n-1}b^2 + ......... + nab^{n-1}i^{n-1} + b^ni^n$.  And the if you add up that long equation there is no reason the imabinare part (which happens to be the sum of the odd terms) should be zero.

Example   $(1 + \sqrt 3i)^3  = 1^3 + 3*1^2\sqrt 3i + 3*1*(\sqrt 3)^2(i)^2 + (\sqrt 3)^3i^3 =$

$1 + 3\sqrt 3i - 9  - 3\sqrt 3i= (1-9) + (3\sqrt 3-3\sqrt 3)i = -8 +0i = -8$.

The imaginary part is a combination of powers of the real and imaginary part that combine to $0$.  And the $(Im z)^3i^3$ wasn't zero but only *combined* in part to get the Imaginary part of $0$.